# GenericMemoryCell in class GenericMemoryCell<T> cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

I would like to the program to print the returns from method `readA()` and `readB()` but I am getting an error from `main` stating that `valueB` requires `String,String` because of my constructor `GenericMemoryCell()`. But if I need to receive and store 2 parameters via the constructor, wouldn't I have to send 2 parameters to the constructor as shown below? How can I go about assigning only 1 String to `valueB`?

```
public class GenericMemoryCell<T>{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericMemoryCell<String> valueA = new GenericMemoryCell<String>("1", "1"); 
        GenericMemoryCell<String> valueB = new GenericMemoryCell<String>("1"); 
        System.out.println("storedValueA: " + valueA.readA());
        System.out.println("storedValueB: " + valueB.readB());
    }

    public GenericMemoryCell(T storedValueA, T storedValueB)
    { this.storedValueA = storedValueA; this.storedValueB = storedValueB; writeA(storedValueA); writeB(storedValueB); }

    public T readA()
    { return storedValueA; }

    public T readB()
    { return storedValueB; }

    private T storedValueA, storedValueB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create `GenericMemoryCell` passing a single parameter you need to add a second constructor with a single parameter.

Here is an example for a single param constructor which just calls the two param constructor, passing a null for the second value:

```
public GenericMemoryCell(T storedValueA, T storedValueB) {
    ...
}

public GenericMemoryCell(T storedValueA) {
    this(storedValueA, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how go about assigning only 1 String to valueB by creating one more constructor with a single parameter:

```
public GenericMemoryCell(T storedValueB) {
    this.storedValueB = storedValueB;       
}
```

So, now your class looks like as follows. I have edited a few places to improve it. Like in your constructor with two parameters, there is no need to call:    `writeA(storedValueA)` and `writeB(storedValueB)`.

GenericMemoryCell.java

```
    public class GenericMemoryCell<T> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GenericMemoryCell<String> valueA = new GenericMemoryCell<String>("1", "2");
        GenericMemoryCell<String> valueB = new GenericMemoryCell<String>("3");
        System.out.println("valueA (A): " + valueA.readA());
        System.out.println("valueA (B): " + valueA.readB());
        System.out.println("valueB (A): " + valueB.readA());
        System.out.println("valueB (B): " + valueB.readB());
    }

    public GenericMemoryCell(T storedValueA, T storedValueB) {
        this.storedValueA = storedValueA;
        this.storedValueB = storedValueB;
    }

    public GenericMemoryCell(T storedValueB) {
        this.storedValueB = storedValueB;
    }

    public void writeB(T storedValueB) {
        this.storedValueB = storedValueB;

    }

    public void writeA(T storedValueA) {
        this.storedValueA = storedValueA;

    }

    public T readA() {
        return storedValueA;
    }

    public T readB() {
        return storedValueB;
    }

    private T storedValueA, storedValueB;
}
```